# Radio button change not firing

Tags: angular

For some reason, my `(change)` event isn't firing... any idea why?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 0.5em; padding-bottom: 2em">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
    {{ selectedCategory }}
    <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" [value]="'Web, Software and Mobile Development'" name="step1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" (change)="onSelectedCategoryChange($event)">
        <label class="custom-control-label">Web, Software and Mobile Development</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" [value]="'Graphics Design'" name="step1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" (change)="onSelectedCategoryChange($event)>
        <label class="custom-control-label">Graphics Design</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" [value]="'Writing and Translation'" name="step1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" (change)="onSelectedCategoryChange($event)>
        <label class="custom-control-label">Writing and Translation</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
  onSelectedCategoryChange(event: any) {
    console.log(`it works with... ${event}`);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a verifiable code, it works for me, see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrjkxc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Its working fine. Think the issue is that I am trying to call it from a modal

Answer (score 1):

use **`(ngModelChange)`** and pass the variable

```
 <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" [value]="'Web, Software and Mobile Development'" name="step1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" (ngModelChange)="onSelectedCategoryChange(selectedCategory)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngModelChange`. Also, look at the console. Maybe there will be an error in your function as well.